# SPD 2013 Workflow BadRequest

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, sharepoint-rest-api

I am stuck getting a BadRequest when trying to post to a list. I can't see what the problem is. I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction:

I believe my Request header and metadata are configured properly...am I missing something?

This is the URL I'm calling in the App Step for posting to the list in the subsite:

`https://sharepoint.sites.co/teams/it/onboarding/office/john doe/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Key Employee Information')/items`

Please let me know if more info needed
enter image description here
[image]

Comment: Can you specify all of your variables? The Accept, the metadata Dictionary?

Comment: which call failed the first one or that at app step , should you also check this article https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/

Comment: the one inside the app step

Comment: Check the properties of the app step. Make sure you have a variable in the RequestHeaders. If that doesn't work, I'd suggest emailing yourself the ResponseHeaders and ResponseContent, that will usually point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks...I getting this error from the ResponseContent:                          {"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"An entry without a type name was found, but no expected type was specified. To allow entries without type information, the expected type must also be specified when the model is specified."}}}

Comment: Is "KeyEmployeeInformation" the name of the list or are there spaces in it? (e.g. "Key Employee Information"). You most likely need the internal name which would be something like "Key_x0020_Employee_x0020_Information"

Comment: The ListItemEntityTypeFullName is SP.Data.KeyEmployeeInformationListItem as I have it

Comment: WOW!...using type instead of Type made this work...type string SP.Data.KeyEmployeeInformationListItem

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**: I had to change the my Metadata2 (per screenshot) Dictionary to use **t**ype instead of **T**ype to make this work:

> type
>   string
>   SP.Data.KeyEmployeeInformationLisItem

Interestingly enough I did not have this issue with doing the same thing not using the app step.

Answer (score 1):

Though I am late on this, thought someone who visit after this will get help:

I had the same issue. What I missed was the "Call HTTP Web Service Properties" -> settings "RequestHeaders" to Variable:RequestHeader (this name might vary according to the variable name)

[image: properties]

[image: property details]

I didn't set the RequestHeaders and got OK response but no results. After I set the variable then its working.

Cheers!

Kamrul

Answer (score 0):

Have you done setting as mentioned under header "Granting full control permission to a workflow" in below mentioned link 
[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396.)

In case you have not followed, that might be reason for bad request.

Comment: I had already done that